# UI element is outside of ConstraintLayout in Android Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-constraintlayout

I have a Column with variable number of text lines, and I want to add it in ConstraintLayout with conditions:

- the column should be scrollable - OK;
- the column should be above of "Center text" element - OK;
- the column should NOT go outside of ConstraintLayout (blue) - Not OK;

[Not OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A082U.png)

Note: it's simplified example, I have to use ConstraintLayout.

The only thing I found to solve my problem is to use ".requiredHeight(187.dp)" modifier. I think I can calculate the exact value of dp using OnGloballyPositioned modifier.
But I don't like this approach and looking for a better way...

[OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiwyW.png)

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val lst = remember { (1..50).map { "text text $it" } }

    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .padding(top = 100.dp, bottom = 100.dp)
    ) {
        ConstraintLayout(
            modifier
                .background(Color.Blue.copy(alpha = 0.2f))
                .fillMaxSize()
                .imePadding()
        ) {
            val (centerText, report) = createRefs()

            Text("Center Text",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .constrainAs(centerText) {
                        top.linkTo(parent.top)
                        bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                    }
            )

            Column(modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Yellow.copy(alpha = 0.2f))
                .constrainAs(report) {
                    bottom.linkTo(centerText.top)
                }
                //.requiredHeight(187.dp)
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            ) {
                lst.forEach {
                    Text(it)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```